# Finding ROW number based on 2 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, match, row, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am guessing how to get exact raw number based on 2 criteria, as you can see from picture below I have 2 data tables, I must find exact raw number from right table where located information from left table based on 2 Matches -(TIME and EXT). Thank you for your time. Working platform google sheets.
[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TIMEVALUE(E2:E)&A2:A, 
 {TIMEVALUE(J2:J)&O2:O, ROW(F2:F)}, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Check please, Ive posted screen below

Comment: @MykytaRiabchynskyi can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1osWLQ1JEv_77GevbfHhbSCIDbnkFSLviSjR2OCoi5-Q/edit?usp=sharing